# Protractor Unable to access a specific element that has its class shared other elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, aurelia, e2e-testing

I'm trying to access a specific element but the element name is used among other elements in the same page

This is the html

```html
<div class="details of buyer">
  <div class="field">
  <small>Balance</small>
  <div>5000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <small>Lodgements</small>
  <div>108,000.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <small>Max Withdrawal</small>
  <div>107,561.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <small>Credits</small>
  <div>-</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <small>Interest Rate</small>
  <div>-</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <small>Net Gain</small>
  <div>-</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <small>Net Yield</small>
  <div>-</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I'm trying to retrieve "107,561.00" from the following
`<small>Max Withdrawal</small>
<div>107,561.00</div>`

I've tried this in my page object file but it returns "Index Out of Bound"....
`var checkBalance= element.all(by.css('div.field> small> div')).get(2);`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get it with :

```
$$('div.field div').get(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use custom selectors for my Protractor code, it's much more sustainable:

```
  <div class="field">
    <small data-custom-selector="max-withdrawal-text">Max Withdrawal</small>
    <div data-custom-selector="max-widthdrawal-amount">107,561.00</div>
  </div>

  var checkBalance = element(by.css('[data-custom-selector="max-widthdrawal-amount"]'));
```

You can name **data-custom-selector** to whatever you want, aslong as you keep the **data-** part, other examples: **data-test-select**, **data-test-ptr**